# card.io library linking errors with Xcode 6.3 (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, card.io

I am running Xcode 6.3 and I'm using card.io's iOS SDK 5.2.0.

Here's the error:

> duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOPostalCodeTextFieldDelegate.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOPostalCodeTextFieldDelegate.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOConfig.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOConfig.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOView.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/comcubatormica/Downloads/card.io-iOS-SDK-master/CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOView.o)
>   ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I solve this?

Comment: @Andrea : Code is useless, it's a library linking issue

Comment: I didn't see in your question that you already said you're using Xcode 6.3. This is definitely the problem here. Try updating to Xcode 7, or go back to using card.io SDK 5.1.1.

Answer (score 5):

You should update Xcode to the latest version, Xcode 7. As stated in card.io's changelog for version 5.2.0:

> **The library is now built with Xcode 7.0.** It has Bitcode enabled which
>   does significantly increase the static library. However, when an app
>   is compiled and distributed by the App Store, the app size should not
>   significantly increase compared to before Bitcode enablement. **You must
>   also use Xcode 7 since previous versions of Xcode are not fully
>   compatible with Bitcode enabled libraries.**